# Node.js não roda corretamente

Tags: json, react

Senhores Bom dia, tarde, noite,
Eu estou com este problemas já a alguns dias, e agora é crucial eu corrigi-lo, porem minha experiência é 0 com Nod.js, React, alguém pode me socorrer?

O que já fiz; Apaguei as pastas node_module e pack-block.json, varias vezes e reinstalei tudo, porem nada resolve, rodei alguns códigos diferente para linux (uso linux) mesmo assim não houve efeito. Por favor alguém pode me ajudar a sair dessa fazer?

[image: aqui fiz algumas configurações para rodar, npm start dev, que não funcionou.]

[image: Aqui esta o erro completo.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse erro ocorre quando você tenta **executar o arquivo e o node não consegue encontra-lo**, verifique se você está passando o local correto do arquivo server.js,

Na foto, seu arquivo está dentro da pasta `src`, então considerando que no seu terminal você esteja na pasta raiz, você deve executar seu programa utilizando:

```
node src/server.js
```

Acredito que por um descuido você esteja tentando executar da forma errada: `node server.js`

Comment: Olha me desculpa o ignorancia nesta minha jornada, mas poderia ser especifico, como eu add, esse código que me indica, o que exatamente eu faria? Mais uma vez desculpe, eu realmente não entendi.

Comment: Dentro do vscode, com o projeto aberto, abra um terminal clicando na aba superior "terminal" e selecionando a opção "novo terminal". Já aberto, apenas copie e cole o primeiro código que eu mencionei, (node src/server.js), após isso aperte ENTER e ele ja deverá executar o seu arquivo server.js

Comment: Obrigado, agora preciso verificar como abrir ambos os servidores para terminar. Agradeço.